# How do I add a smooth transition between video loops in SwiftUI with AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I currently have a video player that plays a looped video for a certain amount of times. 
I would now  like to add a smooth transition between each loop, for example a blur. Does anyone know how to do it with my current code? Is there a function that can be easily integrated in my code or an attribute?
Appreciate any help!

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation


// MARK: ExerciseVideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable
struct ExerciseVideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var increaseRepetitions: () -> Void
    var videoUrl: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        LoopingVideoPlayerView(repetitions: increaseRepetitions, videoUrl: videoUrl)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // Do nothing here
    }
}


// MARK: LoopingVideoPlayerView: UIView
class LoopingVideoPlayerView: UIView {
    // MARK: Stored properties
    var increaseRepetitions: () -> Void
    var videoUrl: URL
    private var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    // MARK: Initialization
    init(repetitions: @escaping () -> Void, videoUrl: URL) {
        self.increaseRepetitions = repetitions
        self.videoUrl = videoUrl
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // Load Video
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl)

        // Setup Player
        let player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        // Loop
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: playerItem) //evtl. time range?

        // Play
        //discuss: Stop video loop after number of desired repetitions is reached
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.increaseRepetitionCount),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: nil)
        player.play()
    }

    // MARK: Methods
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }


    // MARK: Whatever that is
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func increaseRepetitionCount() {
        increaseRepetitions()
    }
}


// MARK: ExerciseVideoPlayer_Previews: PreviewProvider
struct ExerciseVideoPlayer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        guard let videoUrl = URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_10MB.mp4") else {
            fatalError("videoURL not found")
        }
        return ExerciseVideoPlayer(increaseRepetitions: {}, videoUrl: videoUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to solve the same thing.. I have two players overlaid each other and I am trying to create the transition between them by manipulating opacity but it does not work well :/